# how should i store this image?

Tags: file, size

I currently have a bunch of tiny images that i am saving to the server in a folder.

> Would it be more convenient to store the base64 string into the
>   database and when needed pull it out?

I am ultimately looking for a way to conserve disk space, the method i am looking for will need to be able to withstand heavy traffic. 4M users minimum.

All 4M users will be looking at the image.

Would it be bad to retrieve data like that so often?

If i am using the database i will be using mysqli with PHPmyadmin.

EXPERIMENT:
Testing with image: Cute.jpeg
Size: 2.65kb
Size on Disk: 4.00kb

Base64 string:

```
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
```

Base64 string length: 3628

Test:
Varchar(3628) is 3629 bytes, with 1 byte reserved for byte length.

So the total size for the string is ~3.5kb

Conclusion: I save about 0.5kb

Things i might not have considered Mysqli table byte size. If the table byte size reserve is 0.5kb or more then This would be irrational, and i should store my images locally.

Comment: How many bytes would a varchar have to be in order to hold a base64 image? I have a base64 which is 8015 characters long

Comment: I found this link but i still want to know what you guys think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790514/how-much-real-storage-is-used-with-a-varchar100-declaration-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing the base64 image  into a database will not conserve disk space; however, If you are considering storing the image in a database you should look into blob objects.

Answer (score -1):

First, if you're storing binary data in the database, you should really look at the BLOB family of data types (LONGBLOB, TINYBLOB, etc). Forget worries about saving 0.5kb of storage space; use the proper type and minimize the amount of other conversion you have to do. Just my two cents.

If you're worried about heavy traffic, I don't think storing the file itself in the database is the way to go at all. You could run some benchmark tests yourself to determine the amount of overhead involved, but from what I've seen it's often pretty standard in those situations to store the file on disk and store the path only in the database (and metadata or whatever else you need). That way you don't overburden the database (and if you need to scale, I find it easier to scale up your file system and/or webserver than to increase your database capacity).