# MySQL: varchar(64) vs. varchar(255), is there a difference for small strings?

Tags: mysql, storage, varchar

Is there a difference when storing the string "hello" in a column of varchar(64) or varchar(255), assuming all environments(engine, charset .etc) are the same? (For example, the engine automatically allocate space for maximum length or padding up string)

To give some context, I have a case where I will store texts of length less than 64 for 99% of time while there will be text between length 64 and 255 for the remaining 1% of time .

Now if there is a significant overhead for varchar(255) then I will create a separate table for the long string case but if there isn't any overhead then I will just declare the column as varchar(255).

The closest answer I could find is the following question:
[How much real storage is used with a varchar(100) declaration in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790514/how-much-real-storage-is-used-with-a-varchar100-declaration-in-mysql)

However it did not answer my question precisely.

Comment: Which parts did the other question leave unanswered?

Comment: It did not say whether the string will be padded up to the defined length, which is exactly what I was concerned about.

Comment: Why do you care about that? Also, please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Also, using a seperate table for "longer" texts does not sound like good database design. How would you effiiciently run queries in such a setup?

Comment: I care about that because the table will have millions of rows and disk storage could be significantly affected which means more expensive cost

Comment: And indeed using a separate table is not a good design but I could write code in the Laravel side to handle that (which takes time and debugging). Fortunately that was unnecessary as the question is answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Some people just use `VARCHAR(255)` for all short strings columns. For `CHAR` columns, all strings will padded with blanks up to the defined length.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I will accept once the time limit reaches.