# In MySQL 8, if I have some data in a column of type varchar, and later on set it to NULL, will space be reclaimed?

Tags: mysql, innodb, varchar

In MySQL 8 (InnoDB), suppose I have a column of type varchar(100). I initially populate it with a string of of 50 characters. My understanding is that this should take up 51 bytes of space (50 for the string and 1 to store its length).

Now, lets say I execute an update query and set this particular record to NULL. Will 50 bytes of storage be reclaimed?

I've tried to experiment with this, the varchar records are being set to NULL, but db size remains unchanged. I also ran FLUSH TABLES and ANALYZE TABLE [TABLENAME] between runs - but the size is unchanged. I want to know if this is expected behaviour.

Comment: Relevant to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790514/how-much-real-storage-is-used-with-a-varchar100-declaration-in-mysql

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The thread above is different from what I am asking. It is just explaining varchar behaviour (whether it still requires some space even if it is NULL) but that is not relevant to my question. What I need to find out is that if I already have a string in a varchar field and I update it to NULL, is the difference between storage requirements of NULL and my original string reclaimed?

Comment: *I want to know if this is expected behaviour.* Yes. If you want to claim unused space then run OPTIMIZE TABLE. From the other side the only priority for DBMS is the speed and not the disk space, so claiming the disk space makes sense only when the percent of unused space is really high (at least 70-80%).

Comment: @Akina I ran OPTIMIZE TABLE (Note that this is InnoDB so it actually did a recreate + analyze) but there seems to be no change in size yet again.

Comment: Do not forget about block granularity. Also take into account that there exists a setting which defines the percent of unused space per block (which decreases the splits amount). You may query the amount of unused space in the table body from the statistic tables and look does the optimizing is reasonable.

Comment: There will be edge cases where `OPTIMIZE` _increases_ the disk footprint.  If you want to discuss further; please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SHOW TABLE STATUS`.